# SDL/C++ (Accelerated) Black Screen

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to make some kind of 'engine' with C++/SDL. So I followed the LazyFoo's Tutorial and searched others places/videos about it [SDL/C++].
Everything was fine, until I organized my code in 2 Classes. It was just Game.h/Game.cpp and main.cpp, but I thought that would be good to separate the part of the code that loads Images from the Game class that loads and destroys the Surfaces/Textures (Game class).

So I literally copy/pasted the code to another class. What I copy/pasted was the two boolean functions textureBMP and textureIMG everything remains the same. And before I copy/pasted the code to another class, everything was working fine, so I don't know what is making this.

Another little question, is the way I'm organizing the code the right way? I want to have good habits straight in the beginning, even with small projects, such as this little project just for learning.
Thanks in advance!

Image.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"

class Image
{
public:
    Image();
    ~Image();

    Game game;

    SDL_Surface *gBMP = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *tBMP = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *gIMG = NULL;
    SDL_Texture *tIMG = NULL;

    bool textureBMP(char *mediaLocation, bool SetColorKey, int red, int green, int blue);
    bool textureIMG(char *mediaLocation, int imgFlags);
};
```

Image.cpp

```
#include "Image.h"

Image::Image()
{
}


Image::~Image()
{
}

bool Image::textureBMP(char *mediaLocation, bool SetColorKey, int red, int green, int blue) {

    gBMP = SDL_LoadBMP(mediaLocation);

    if (gBMP == NULL) {
        printf("Nao foi possivel carregar a imagem %s,por causa do seguinte erro: \n %s \n", mediaLocation, SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    else {

        if (SetColorKey) {

            SDL_SetColorKey(gBMP, 1, SDL_MapRGB(gBMP->format, red, green, blue));

        }

        tBMP = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(game.renderer, gBMP);
        SDL_FreeSurface(gBMP);

    }

    return true;
}

bool Image::textureIMG(char *mediaLocation, int imgFlags) {

    if (!(IMG_Init(imgFlags) & imgFlags)) {

        printf("SDL_image não pode ser inicializada! SDL_image Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    else {

        gIMG = IMG_Load(mediaLocation);
        tIMG = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(game.renderer, gIMG);
        SDL_FreeSurface(gIMG);

    }

    return true;
}
```

Game.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Game
{

public:

    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

    bool running;

    SDL_Event event;

    SDL_Window *gWindow = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *gScreenSurface = NULL;

    Game();
    ~Game();

    bool initEngine(char *windowName);

    void freeSurface(SDL_Surface *surfaceName);
    void freeTexture(SDL_Texture *textureName);
    void destroyRenderer();
    void destroyWindow();

};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{
}


Game::~Game()
{
}

bool Game::initEngine(char *windowName) {

    bool initSucess = true;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {

        printf("A Engine não foi iniciada pelo seguinte erro: \n %s \n", SDL_GetError());
        initSucess = false;
        return initSucess;
    }
    else {

        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(windowName, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

        if (gWindow == NULL) {

            printf("A janela não pode ser criada pelo seguinte erro: \n %s \n", SDL_GetError());
            initSucess = false;
            return initSucess;

        }
        else {

            gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow);

        }

    }


    return initSucess;
}

void Game::freeSurface(SDL_Surface *surfaceName) {

    SDL_FreeSurface(surfaceName);
    surfaceName = NULL;

}

void Game::freeTexture(SDL_Texture *textureName) {

    SDL_DestroyTexture(textureName);
    textureName = NULL;

}

void Game::destroyRenderer() {

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    renderer = NULL;

}

void Game::destroyWindow() {

    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow); 
    gWindow = NULL;

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Game.h"
#include "Image.h"

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {

    Game game;
    Image img;

    if (!game.initEngine("TESTE")) {
        printf("Falha ao iniciar! \n");
        return 0;
    }

    game.running = true;

    if (!img.textureBMP("res/bouncingball.bmp", true, 255, 0, 255))
        printf("Falha ao iniciar imagem!\n");

    if (!img.textureIMG("res/Tulips.jpg", IMG_INIT_JPG))
        printf("Falha ao iniciar imagem! \n");

    SDL_Rect stretchRect{ (game.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) - 50, (game.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - 50, 100, 100 };

    SDL_Rect stretchRect2{ 0, 0, game.SCREEN_WIDTH, game.SCREEN_HEIGHT };

    while (game.running) {

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&game.event) != 0) {

            switch (game.event.type) {

            case SDL_QUIT:

                game.running = false;
                game.freeSurface(game.gScreenSurface);
                game.freeTexture(img.tBMP);
                game.freeTexture(img.tIMG);
                game.destroyRenderer();
                game.destroyWindow();
                IMG_Quit();
                SDL_Quit();
                break;

            }//Switch Event END


        } // PollEvent END

        SDL_RenderCopy(game.renderer, img.tIMG, nullptr, &stretchRect2);
        SDL_RenderCopy(game.renderer, img.tBMP, nullptr, &stretchRect);
        SDL_RenderPresent(game.renderer);

        SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    }// game.running END

    return 0;
}
```

[PrintScreen of the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Ovk.png)

Comment: If every Image object has a separate Game object, how would you render to one renderer?

Comment: I can't think in another way to acess the renderer, maybe making it static?

Comment: @sadmachine static will work. Passing renderer upon image creation will too. What you have now is a NULL.

Comment: There are several ways to do what you want. But I think the most convinient is not to store a Game object in your Image class. When you load an image, you pass your renderer with a reference. So, no duplicate is made, and you don't have to store your renderer in every Image object.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes, and now it works properly. I changed two things, the first was the part that was giving the black screen, and now the functions look like this:

Image.h

```
bool textureBMP(char *mediaLocation, <...>, SDL_Renderer *render);
bool textureIMG(char *mediaLocation, <...>, SDL_Renderer *render);
```

main.cpp

```
if (!img.textureIMG("res/Tulips.jpg", IMG_INIT_JPG, game.renderer))
```

And, the other change was that, before Image.h was including Game.h, and, in main.cpp I was including Game.h, and Image.h and this would create an error right? 
Because of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Obs: I created an answer because the comment doesn't allow codes

Comment: Answering your own question (and accepting it) is fine as long as it is really an answer. If you need to comment, it is usually better to edit question (not in this case, it is fine - just for the future). I fail to see why you could have had problem with include guards - they are to skip parts of code, not to explicitly produce errors.

Comment: Okay, I will try to remember it, Thanks!